# Can Atlassian read/copy my source code by using SourceTree

Tags: git, security, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a question:

Will our code pass through Atlassian servers when I use **SourceTree** in combination with **Visual Studio Online**. I added my **access token** to the git repository connection string in SourceTree. Will the SourceTree application download direct or will it read my code and maybe keep a back-up somewhere or pass it through Atlassian Servers.

This question is because we do not want other companies to read our code at this moment. Is it safe to use SourceTree at this time with the above in mind?

Comment: If you don’t trust them, don’t use them.

Comment: But maybe someone knows if they do or don't. Or tested the network traffic. Just to be sure.

Comment: In the mean time, why not use git in the command line and cut out any doubt about SourceTree?

Comment: we already do at the moment. But the added value of the visual representation is of course evident. So we would like to transit to the application if possible.

Comment: pretty sure SourceTree is just a visualization of what git can do on the command line. No data goes through Atlassian servers, its all just git.

Comment: SourceTree is a very popular application. If it's sending your source code to Atlassian, they are going to get sued into oblivion.

Comment: @GoedWare SourceTree is the GUI to handle your local git repo. For VSTS and Atlassian servers, they are different servers can hosted remote git repo. So where does your remote repo located, VSTS, Atlassian servers or both?

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason it should, Sourcetree should make a direct connection to Visual Studio Online, and there should be no need for anything to pass through Atlassian Servers.

However, as we all know, applications like to phone home details when errors occur, so you should probably check your privacy agreement and privacy settings to make sure it is acting like you'd expect.